# How to use the Polynomial Trendline Formula

Tags: excel

So the blue line graph has values from column CM (x values are in column CF, sorry for the confusing presentation). I want to recreate the polynomial trendline that I had excel generate for it, which is what I'm trying to do in column CH, as you can see from the formula bar.

Excel gives me the formula y = -0,0006x^2 + 0,013x + 0,1878 (shown on the chart) which I then have entered into the values in column CH.

The result is unfortunately not even close (displayed as the orange line graph). Is there any person here sharp enough on maths to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

This is the formula to obtain `2nd Order Polynomial Trendline`:

```
y = (c2 * x^2) + (c1 * x) + b

c2: =INDEX(LINEST(y,x^{1,2}),1)
c1: =INDEX(LINEST(y,x^{1,2}),1,2)
 b: =INDEX(LINEST(y,x^{1,2}),1,3)
```

So now, just examined your formula, you have incorrect parameters (`b, c1 and c2`) used so the result is different.

Here are the formulas I used to obtain these three parameters:

```
c2: =INDEX(LINEST($CM$1234:$CM$1262,$CF$1234:$CF$1262^{1,2}),1)
c1: =INDEX(LINEST($CM$1234:$CM$1262,$CF$1234:$CF$1262^{1,2}),1,2)
 b: =INDEX(LINEST($CM$1234:$CM$1262,$CF$1234:$CF$1262^{1,2}),1,3)
```

Then I got:

```
c2 (cell CG1227) = -0.05675
c1 (cell CG1228) = -0.04025
 b (cell CG1229) = 0.25509
```

Now, from `cell CH1234`, this formula is used:

```
=($CG$1227*CF1234^2)+($CG$1228*CF1234)+$CG$1229
```

I have the outcome matched with the Polynomial Trendline.  Try and see if this works for you.

Comment: Yes, you're completely right. I have no idea why Excel is showing the wrong formula for its polynomial trendline - but I googled my way into how to use the linest function and it worked just as I wanted to! Thank you either way! =)

Comment: I am using Office Excel 2016, there is a bug in the Polynomial (and possibly other trendline) formula displayed in the chart whereby y = c2.x2+c1.x+b is displayed as y = c2.x2-c1.x+b. The addition sign is wrongly displayed as subtraction.